# What or Who is XPMUser in Word, OpenXML or PowerTool?

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml, productivity-power-tools

I am creating a document using both OpenXML and PowerTool for OpenXML and the author of the document is XPMUser. Where does it come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the initial configuration [`Windows XP Mode`](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8002) (`XPM`) after installing the free and full license `Windows XP` in a virtual machine `Virtual PC Windows 7`, the user must set a password for the default `XPMUser` account. By default, `Windows XP` will save mode and remember the username and password to log data to `XPMUser` `Windows Virtual PC`, you can log on to the desktop, where the direct integration features are enabled.

Comment: Thank you. Oh I guess the document was created long time ago.